# SQL statement that gets records where the datetime column has not passed

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime

In my login script I have a password reset function that creates a record that includes a unique token and an expiry date (datetime field) of 48 hours from the time the password reset was requested.

How do I create an SQL statement that will check the token is still valid by only getting the record if the expiry date has not expired e.g.

**SELECT * FROM resetpasstable WHERE expires > now()**

I'm kind of new to all this so any help appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried that query? What happens when you use it? What results do you get?

Comment: Why doesn't your query work?  It appears okay to me

Comment: So are you trying to get records where the expiration column is less than 48 hours old?

Comment: I tested in MySQL, now() function is OK. You are all good.

Comment: Well it would appear I should have just gone ahead and tried it. Thanks all for commenting and helping out.